# I cannot get this to redirect. The timer works but it doesn't go anywhere. I need this to redirect to another webpage

Tags: javascript, timer, http-redirect

```
<script>
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    var end =setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            //window.location = "http://www.YouTube.com";
            clearInterval(end);
        }
    }, 1000);}

window.onload = function () {
    var fiveMinutes = 5,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>Redirect in <span id="time">05:00</span></div>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

</form>
```

I cannot get this to actually redirect. the countdown works but it doesn't redirect. I just get the timer. the timer counts down and hits zero and it goes absolutely nowhere.

Comment: Are there any errors in your browser's console? I've tested your code both locally (works) and on jsfiddle (generally works - redirection is attempted, but blocked because of the way jsfiddle works). There's the issue of the countdown not being performed properly, but that doesn't impede the redirection.

Comment: I don't think so, I'm trying to help my son with his homework. I'm absolutely lost 

Comment: So something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/fsL9kuoj/) is not working for you? Please note that this is the code you posted (along with the erroneous countdown - 5 minutes being treated as 5 seconds).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, --timer will always return 4 since 5 was set as the initial value, thus you will never be redirected. You should add a else block to reduce timer value by 1 after every 60 000 milliseconds.